# SQLalchemy | fastAPI. Trying to add a new row in association table gives KeyError

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm, many-to-many, fastapi, pydantic

So I have a fastAPI project that uses sqlalchemy to connect to a postgresql database.
I use alembic to build the database and have version control on it.

My issue is now that everything works quite like it should with the many to many relationship. All stocks show the portfolio they belong to, and all portfolios show the stocks they have in them (This was tested with manually entering the data in PGAdmin).
The issue now is that every time I try to add a new connection (add a stock to a portfolio) it throws me a "Key-Error".

Here is the models.py:

```py
class PortfolioStock(Base):
   __tablename__ = "portfolio_stocks"
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   stock_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("stocks.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
   portfolio_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("portfolios.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
   count = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
   buy_in = Column(Float, nullable=True)
   stock = relationship("Stock", back_populates="portfolios")
   portfolio = relationship("Portfolio", back_populates="stocks")
   #a lot of these proxy associations here because of another bug I encountered
   #basically every column in the two models associated here have a association proxy row.(couldn't find another fix)
   stock_created_at = association_proxy(target_collection="stock", attr="created_at")
   portfolio_name = association_proxy(target_collection="portfolio", attr="name")
   def __init__(self, portfolio=None, stock=None, buy_in=None, count=None):
       self.portfolio = portfolio
       self.stock = stock
       self.buy_in = buy_in
       self.count = count


class Stock(Base):
   __tablename__ = "stocks"

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
   ...
   status = Column(Integer, nullable=False, server_default="0")
   portfolios = relationship("PortfolioStock", back_populates="stock")


class Portfolio(Base):
   __tablename__ = "portfolios"

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
   name = Column(String, nullable=False)
   user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
   monetary_goal = Column(Float, nullable=True)
   dividends_goal = Column(Float, nullable=True)
   created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=text("now()"))
   stocks = relationship("PortfolioStock", back_populates="portfolio")
```

Here are some snippets to show what I do in the fastapi route.
First i get the portfolio in question and the stocks that are passed into the body.
I iterate over the stocks and grab the corresponding entry in the DB for each one.
And finally I try to just add these stocks to the list that contains all the models that are in the portfolio.

```py
portfolio = db.query(models.Portfolio).filter(models.Portfolio.id == portfolio_id).first()
   for stock in stock_ids:
        stock = db.query(models.Stock).filter(models.Stock.id == stock_id).first()
        portfolio.stocks.append(stock)
        setattr(stock, "status", "1")
    db.add(portfolio)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(portfolio)
    return portfolio
```

And here is the error message that I receive when I try to call this route from postman.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 375, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 259, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 84, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 656, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 259, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 61, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 222, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(dependant=dependant, values=values, is_coroutine=is_coroutine)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 159, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 39, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 28, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(func, *args, cancellable=cancellable,
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 818, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 754, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/./api/routers/stock.py", line 151, in add_stock_to_portfolio
    portfolio.stocks.append(stock)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 1169, in append
    item = __set(self, item, _sa_initiator)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 1134, in __set
    item = executor.fire_append_event(item, _sa_initiator)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 753, in fire_append_event
    return self.attr.fire_append_event(
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1330, in fire_append_event
    value = fn(state, value, initiator or self._append_token)
  File "/home/maxi/dev/captstone_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1632, in emit_backref_from_collection_append_event
    child_impl = child_state.manager[key].impl
KeyError: 'portfolio'
```

I have already tried to rename all relationships to figure out where exactly the error is coming from.
And it seems to be that t he relationship of `stock = relationship("Stock", back_populates="portfolios")` is a culprit of the issue.

Looking in debugging mode it seems that the model I'm trying to access is not having the correct keys in it, so my guess is that I'm either making the new association wrong and it's not `portfolio.stocks.append(stock)` (which worked before I fixed another issue) or that the relationships are wrong / something is missing to make it work.

I would really greatly appreciate some suggestions.

If you need additional information please let me know.